# How to find a shapefile's correct EPSG code

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, epsg

My company uses inhouse software in order to survey and we need to manually specify an EPSG code in order to set up a project and then add shapefiles. However, there is some confusion on my part because this needs to be an EPSG code and the numeric code for the projections I often cannot find as an EPSG code

As an example, today I found out that I messed up a project because I could not find an EPSG code for the [NAD_1983_StatePlane_Maryland_FIPS_1900_Feet projection](https://spatialreference.org/ref/?&search=NAD_1983_StatePlane_Maryland_FIPS_1900_Feet). I cannot use the ESRI or SR-ORG codes, so what would I do next? Reproject all the shapefiles into a similar coordinate system that does have an EPSG code, how do I choose which to use?

Comment: That must be annoying, try https://epsg.io/ or https://spatialreference.org/ for quick reference. IMO spatial reference org has a better search by name; although this site also has Esri and other codes they are clearly labelled as such like this one https://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102685/. The question is what are you expected to do with codes that aren't European Petroleum Survey Group (EPSG) codes? You could use Esri to project to something close or a standard like WGS84/UTM (or Albers or Lamberts) that offers better compatibility with resources (like Google).

Comment: Bear in mind that it may be possible that EPSG (https://epsg.org/home.html) haven't got a definition (and thus code) for your coordinate reference system.  So if you actually mean EPSG code and aren't using that synchronously for coordinate reference system you might be in trouble.  In some cases depending on the software you may be able to construct a definition for a CRS and name it EPSG:nnnnnn to fool the software.

Comment: it seems odd if you are using ESRI ArcGIS-desktop/ArcMap (as tagged) that you can't use an ESRI defined CRS

Answer (score 5):

Note that the current website for the EPSG Registry is https://epsg.org. It supports a search. Using Maryland, it returns 58 CRS, but that includes entries where Maryland is in the extent name or description.

In the ArcGIS coordinate system picker, you can give a search term which will reduce the folders that you have to look through.

The Esri names won't always match the EPSG names. For instance, the corresponding entry in EPSG is "NAD83 / Maryland (ftUS)", 2248. For instance, we included the FIPS ID, because we'd been using it in ArcInfo Workstation, the predecessor to ArcGIS Desktop.

Disclosure: I work for Esri. I am on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG Registry.

Comment: `https://www.epsg.org` gives a "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead"

Comment: @gerrit  Thank you! The correct link omits the www. Fixed. I keep forgetting myself and then wonder why the website doesn't work!